# Windows Update doesn't recognize me as administrator

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, dell-inspiron

Back in 2012, when I first started using my laptop (a Dell model running Windows 8), I changed the Windows Update settings so that it would check with me before downloading/installing any updates. I have a bad habit of forgetting to manually approve the updates, though, so I'd like to change it back to running automatically.

However, the Windows Update box in the Action Center has this message: "Windows Update is set to check with you before downloading and installing updates. These settings are managed by your system administrator," and the "Change settings..." box next to it is grayed out. For some reason, I'm not recognized as the administrator, but only for that particular setting. I can change anything else on the PC that I'd like, including the *other* Windows Update settings. But not that one.

This isn't a huge crisis since I can still manually start the updates, but I'm a little worried that there's something on my PC that I'm not allowed to alter. Does anybody have any idea how to fix the problem?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue,  seemed to happen repeatedly when I was torrenting...I was able to remedy it by manually configuring the registry.  The following are windows updates registry keys (says server but is tested viable from win7 and 8 (.1).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939844%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Once you edit the registry you may need to restart a time or two to be able to use the grayed out drop down box...

Edit1: to ram hound for maintaining a higher standard!

Registry entries that you can use to configure Automatic Updates by using Registry Editor are located in the following subkeys:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Internet Communication Management\Internet Communication

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU

Registry keys for Windows Update

WSUS registry entries for Windows Update are located in the following subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate
The keys and their values are listed in the following table.

Entry name  Data type   Values
AcceptTrustedPublisherCerts
Reg_DWORD
Range = 1|0
1 = Enabled. The WSUS server distributes available signed non-Microsoft updates.

0 = Disabled. The WSUS server does not distribute available signed non-Microsoft updates.

DisableWindowsUpdateAccess
Reg_DWORD
Range = 1|0
1 = Disables access to Windows Update.

0 = Enables access to Windows Update.

ElevateNonAdmins
Reg_DWORD
Range = 1|0
1 = All members of the Users security group can approve or disapprove updates.

0 = Only members of the Administrators security group can approve or disapprove updates.

TargetGroup
Reg_SZ
Name of the computer group to which the computer belongs. This policy is paired with TargetGroupEnabled.
TargetGroupEnabled
Reg_DWORD
Range = 1|0
1 = Use client-side targeting.

0 = Do not use client-side targeting. This policy is paired with TargetGroup.

WUServer
Reg_SZ
HTTP(S) URL of the WSUS server that is used by Automatic Updates and API callers (by default). This policy is paired with WUStatusServer, and both keys must be set to the same value to be valid.
WUStatusServer
Reg_SZ
The HTTP(S) URL of the server to which reporting information is sent for client computers that use the WSUS server that is configured by the WUServer key. This policy is paired with WUServer, and both keys must be set to the same value to be valid.
WSUS registry keys for Internet Explorer

WSUS registry entries for Internet Explorer are located in the following subkey:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
The keys and their values are listed in the following table.

Entry name  Data type   Corresponding Group Policy setting  Values
NoWindowsUpdate
Reg_DWORD
Remove links and access to Windows Update
Prevents users from connecting to the Windows Update website.
Range = 1|0
1 = Enabled. Users cannot connect to the Windows Update website.

0 = Disabled or not configured. Users can connect to the Windows Update website.

WSUS registry keys for Internet communication

WSUS registry entries for Internet communication are located in the following subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Internet Communication Management\Internet Communication
The keys and their values are listed in the following table.

Entry name  Data type   Corresponding Group Policy setting  Values
DisableWindowsUpdateAccess
Reg_DWORD
Turn off access to all Windows Update features
Remove all access to Windows Update.
Range = 1|0
1 = Enabled. All Windows Update features are removed. This includes blocking access to the Windows Update website at http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com, from the Windows Update hyperlink on the Start menu, and also on the Tools menu in Internet Explorer. Windows automatic updating is also disabled; you will neither be notified about nor will you receive critical updates from Windows Update. This setting also prevents Device Manager from automatically installing driver updates from the Windows Update website.

0 = Disabled or not configured. Users will be able to access the Windows Update website and enable automatic updating to receive notifications and critical updates from Windows Update.

WSUS registry key for Windows Update

WSUS registry entry for Windows Update is located in the following subkey:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate
The key and its value is listed in the following table.

Entry name  Data type   Corresponding Group Policy setting  Values
DisableWindowsUpdateAccess
Reg_DWORD
Remove access to use all Windows Update features
Prevents users from connecting to the Windows Update website.
Range = 1|0
1 = Enabled. All Windows Update features are removed.

0 = Disabled or not configured. All Windows Update features are available.

Registry keys for Automatic Update configuration options

The registry entries for Automatic Update configuration options are located in the following subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
The keys and their values are listed in the following table.

Entry name  Data type   Values
AUOptions
Reg_DWORD
Range = 2|3|4|5
2 = Notify before download.

3 = Automatically download and notify of installation.

4 = Automatically download and schedule installation. Only valid if values exist for ScheduledInstallDay and ScheduledInstallTime.

5 = Automatic Updates is required and users can configure it.

AutoInstallMinorUpdates
Reg_DWORD
Range = 0|1
0 = Treat minor updates like other updates.

1 = Silently install minor updates.

DetectionFrequency
Reg_DWORD
Range = n, where n = time in hours (1–22).
Time between detection cycles.

DetectionFrequencyEnabled
Reg_DWORD
Range = 0|1
1 = Enable detection frequency.

0 = Disable custom detection frequency (use default value of 22 hours).

NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers
Reg_DWORD
Range = 0|1
1 = Logged-on user can decide whether to restart the client computer.

0 = Automatic Updates notifies the user that the computer will restart in 15 minutes.

NoAutoUpdate
Reg_DWORD
Range = 0|1
0 = Enable Automatic Updates.

1 = Disable Automatic Updates.

RebootRelaunchTimeout
Reg_DWORD
Range = n, where n = time in minutes (1–1,440).
Time between prompts for a scheduled restart.

RebootRelaunchTimeoutEnabled
Reg_DWORD
Range = 0|1
1 = Enable RebootRelaunchTimeout.

0 = Disable custom RebootRelaunchTimeout(use default value of 10 minutes).

RebootWarningTimeout
Reg_DWORD
Range = n, where n = time in minutes (1–30).
Length, in minutes, of the restart warning countdown after updates have been installed that have a deadline or scheduled updates.

RebootWarningTimeoutEnabled
Reg_DWORD
Range = 0|1
1 = Enable RebootWarningTimeout.

0 = Disable custom RebootWarningTimeout (use default value of 5 minutes).

RescheduleWaitTime
Reg_DWORD
Range = n, where n = time in minutes (1–60).
Time in minutes that Automatic Updates waits at startup before it applies updates from a missed scheduled installation time.

This policy applies only to scheduled installations, not to deadlines. Updates with deadlines that have expired should always be installed as soon as possible.

RescheduleWaitTimeEnabled
Reg_DWORD
Range = 0|1
1 = Enable RescheduleWaitTime .

0 = Disable RescheduleWaitTime (attempt the missed installation during the next scheduled installation time).

ScheduledInstallDay
Reg_DWORD
Range = 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7
0 = Every day.

1 through 7 = the days of the week from Sunday (1) to Saturday (7).

(Only valid if AUOptions = 4.)

ScheduledInstallTime
Reg_DWORD
Range = n, where n = the time of day in 24-hour format (0–23).
UseWUServer
Reg_DWORD
Range = 0|1
1 = The computer gets its updates from a WSUS server.

0 = The computer gets its updates from Microsoft Update.

The WUServer value is not respected unless this key is set.

Comment: It's normal to include the relevant information in your answer instead of just linking to external content

Comment: It would not be prudent to copy paste microsofts entire technet library page for manually updating the registry keys to windows update. It is also going to be her personal preference as to which keys she adjusts or adds to get her desired settings. This is not a dieing link that will fade, it is the technical repository for microsoft, please fix your down vote. ..

Comment: **although I do appreciate the comment attached to said down vote ; )

Comment: I don't find link only answers helpful.  *Please fix your answer* only then will I reconsider my voting choice..  Honestly I shouldn't even respond, since the vote system is anonymous, and you should not  have assumed I was the person who issued the vote you disagree with.  The reason even technical articles written by Microsoft should be quoted is that, Microsoft has a very long history of moving stuff around on their website, and then we end up with old links end up not working.  I don't find it prudent not to include information and making it clear where the instructions came from.